# Clipboard size limit

Tags: windows, clipboard

Is there any limit of the size of data that can be copied to clipboard? I am using VB6 and need to copy blocks of data to the clipboard.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, how about giving us some more detail so we can help you out. If not, this question belongs elsewhere.

Comment: Yes,I am trying to write data to clipboard using vb6.
Thats why I am wondering about its limit.

Comment: As a information: you can think the clipboard buffer is to small while copying text with some &lt;NUL&gt; (ascii 0) characters into an editor. In this case, the problem is not the size of the clipboard, but the editor recognize the &lt;NUL&gt; as the end of the text and don't insert anymore after this character.

Answer (score 42):

Applications call `GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_DDESHARE)` to allocate the memory for data to be stored on the clipboard and make it available to other applications.  For 32-bit applications `GlobalAlloc` can allocate blocks up to 2 GB in size or up to the amount of virtual memory the PC has, whichever is less.  The Windows clipboard does not impose any other size limits.

Comment: What about 64-bit applications?

Answer (score 4):

Most data is copied as a reference rather than the data itself so you can copy most anything any size. Text though is actually copied and from what I know the amount of data is limited to how much ram is currently availiable. Remember this, if vb6 can handle it, I'm sure the clipboard can handle it.

Comment: (-1) Most data not copied by reference. In the simplest case, a string variable in an app is copied into a global memory block, as Jan indicated.  There are some situations where the copy/paste involves pointers to internal storage, but that's usually with proprietary/private formats.  For common things like AnsiString, UnicodeString, RTF, HTML, Bitmap, etc., it's done with shared global memory, which means a second copy of the data has to exist.