# How to Use Copy Append Function in AS400 to Copy Append More Screens (VBScript)?

Tags: vbscript, macros, ibm-midrange

I am trying to use the copy append function to copy hundreds of screens from AS400. It only lets me "Copy Append" about 33 screens before stopping. I am using a VBScript macro to do the copying and navigating. (shown below) Is there a way to copy append more screens? Do you see anything wrong with my code or can suggest a different approach?

Thanks,
Gordon

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

REM This line calls the macro subroutine
subSub1_

sub subSub1_()

dim pagectr, roll

pagectr = 1


   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"

Do

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop



   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

 roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop



   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"


roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"     

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"

roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "7"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"


roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop


   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[left]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "5"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLMacro "[edit-copyappend]"  

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]"


roll = 1

Do

if (roll = pagectr) then
    exit do
end if

   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[roll up]"

roll = roll + 1

Loop





   pagectr = pagectr + 1






REM Wait for 10 seconds = 10000 milliseconds
autECLSession.autECLPS.Wait 5000
Loop



end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[Client/iSeries/IBM i] Access may be limiting the total size of the clipboard.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753270/58061) answer to the SO question [Clipboard size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321866/58061).

*Do you really need to screen scrape as opposed to direct access to the database behind the application?*

One of the great advantages of the midrange system is the ability to access the database directly.

Here are some references to get you started:

- **Windows** [Access iSeries services from the middle tier](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaii%2Frzaii3tiertechs.htm)
- **Linux** [IBM i Access](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/access/linux/guide/index.html)
- **Java** [JT400](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/)