# CTRL+ C how much can I copy

Tags: windows, architecture, copy-paste

Maybe it's answered somewhere but I cant find it.
How much can the `CTRL + C` copy?
For example I wanna copy a 5GB text and paste it somewhere else.
Can I?
 How much is the `data buffer`?

Comment: The data buffer is whatever amount of memory the program can request from Windows. For 64-bit Windows this might be practically unlimited. For 32-bit Windows it will never be more than 3GB and probably much much less.

Comment: why wouldn't you just save the data to a file and then copy/move the file around?

Comment: @MarkRansom are you sure?
can you give me  some reference?

Comment: @KillerB I can only point you to the internals of how the clipboard works, it just kind of derives from there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: sorry I searched a lot but didn't come
deleting it right away

Answer (score 2):

Applications call `GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE or GMEM_DDESHARE)` to allocate the memory for data to be stored on the clipboard and make it available to other applications. For 32-bit applications `GlobalAlloc` can allocate blocks up to 2 GB in size or up to the amount of virtual memory the PC has, whichever is less. The Windows clipboard does not impose any other size limits.

This was an answer provided by Jan Goyvaerts on a similar question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753270/3363156

Comment: Good find, this question is actually a duplicate of that one.