# Copying large data from AgGrid to Clipboard

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a large triangle data set 300x300 in ag-Grid. I'm able to export to CSV/xls, but not able to copy/paste to clipboard using Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V. It works fine for data sets with 85x300. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might have hit the max amount of memory your clipboard can hold:

[Clipboard size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321866/clipboard-size-limit)

Comment: Not sure. I can able to copy the same data which is populated in other grids such as Flexgrid, I just wonder if ag-grid has any max limit to copy the data to clipboard?