# Maximum amount of lines that can be copy/pasted into command prompt

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cmd, command-prompt

I'm using AWS CLI tool to download hundreds of thousands of files. I have almost a million of these one-liners generated from SQL query with different file path that I need to go through:

```
aws s3 cp s3://[myS3FilePath]/17802c9-6d3b-4eef-855a-a6ae0039c7ff/  C:\[MyLocalFilePath]\17802c9-6d3b-4eef-855a-a6ae0039c7ff\ --recursive
```

I've been taking ~1000 lines at a time, pasting them to command prompt, and waiting for them to be iterated through. Works great!
It's quite a time waste doing it in 1000 record batches though. What's the maximum amount of lines that I could paste to CMD without losing any of my download commands?
Could I paste 1.000.000 lines into the command prompt for example and trust that it will iterate through all of them?

Comment: Can you put all of the lines into a .bat file script and run the .bat file script?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321866/clipboard-size-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer is to put all of the one-liners into a .bat file script and run the .bat file script.